# Reauthenticate git (force creating new SSH key for a new user)

Tags: git, ssh

I have a personal and a corporate user at Bitbucket. I wish to use the latter, but the personal account's SSH key might be stuck somewhere in the system, so all commits are getting pushed using my personal account to the corporate repository.

How to force git bash to reauthenticate (ask again for my username and password)?

I've already `cd`'d to `.ssh` folder and moved all files to a new subfolder, but didn't help at all.

Comment: your personal user has access to corporate user's repositories? Anyway just generate new ssh key pair and add public key to your corporate user account (and remove the old one).

Comment: already tried. Seems like it's pulling data from the corporate which has access and pushing from another one o_O

Comment: What do you get if you run `ssh -T git@bibucket.com` ? Maybe remove your added identities by `ssh-add -D` and try adding the only one you use for corporate account.

Comment: Okay. Since then I've deleted the personal account, since there wasn't much on it anyways. But it still uploads using that name. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

The solution turns out to be unrelated to SSH keys.

```
git config --global user.name "my name"
git config --global user.email "my@email.com"
```

It's fixed now.